# Drag and drop not working when you create a dataset (Visual studio/SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2017, dataset, datasource

Hello I Use VS2017 pro,

I have a database (sqlite) and i want to built dataset. I configured SQL provider (EF6 ErikEJ) but drag-and-drop not working and i cant see the fields, i also used SQLite/SQL server compact toolbox, same problem (Drag-and-drop not working)

[image]

Comment: That provider does not support this

Comment: is there a way around the problem ?

Comment: Yes, build the dataset in code.

Comment: you have an example with sqlite ?